# Does f(a,b|c) indicate a and b are both conditioned on c, or only b?

Tags: conditional-probability, notation

Simple question: I know f(a|b,c) indicates a is conditioned on 2 variables b,c however, does f(a,b|c) indicate a and b are conditioned on c, or just b?

If this notation means is a conditioned on both b,c then does f(a,b|c) = f(a|c,b|c)

Comment: What is $f$? What are $a,b,c$? The answer might depend on what these are.

Comment: f is a pdf. a,b,c are just random variables governed by some distributions. I'm thinking very generally.

Comment: There is no _random variable_ named $X \mid Z$ or $Y \mid Z$. The general rule is that _everything_ to the left of $\mid$ is conditioned on _everything_ to the right of $\mid$. Thus, $f_{X,Y\mid Z}(x,y\mid z)$ is the value at the point $(x,y)$ of the _conditional_ joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ given that $Z$ has value $z$. In contrast, $f_{X\mid Z, Y \mid Z}(x,y\mid z)$ or $f_{X\mid Z, Y \mid Z}(x\mid z,y\mid z)$ has no meaning since, as I said upfront, $X\mid Z$ and $Y\mid Z$ are not random variables.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My question was prompted by trying to show using factorization (and joint/conditional pdf definitions) that f(a,b|c) = f(b|c)*f(a|b,c). I'm now more confused than before on how to do this.

Comment: Since I cannot comment, I will make this as an answer.
My mind is very simple. It seems you can use the formular$P(A\cap B)=P(B)P(A|B)$. a=A, B=b|c.

Comment: that's along the lines of what I was thinking. However, given the definition of f(a,b|c) as the conditional joint pdf of both a,b given c, why don't we need to let A=a|c. B = b|c, giving:
f(a,b|c) = f((a|c)|(b|c))*f(b|c)=f(a|b,c)*f(b|c).
Its the middle step in the above that I'm confused about.

Comment: This is even more confusing.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks but it does not seem to be what the OP wants to know. I think his difficulties are greatly exacerbated by the poorly chosen notation that he insists on using, and what should be a straightforward exercise hs become a huge production.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why you are confused, but as said in a comment, the general rule is that everything on the left of $\mid $ is conditioned on everything on the right. By the usual definition,
$$ f(a, b \mid c) = \frac{f(a,b,c)}{f(c)},  $$ assuming that these densities exist.